# Calculation of maximum, minimum, mean & median Round Trip Time of each packet using UDP pinger python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I am a new learner of Python. As part of a homework problem, I am trying to calculate the RTT of each packet sent by the client program. I was able to write the code for client(with the help of stackoverflow community, Kudos) and I am getting the RTT of each successful packet. I have successfully calculated the max, min & average RTT. But the median RTT is not working. I am trying to call a function median and its not working. Giving me an error: **IndexError: list index out of range** Could you please help me? Below is the client code:

```
from socket import *
import datetime
import time

port=input('Port: ')
mylist=[]

def main():
    serverName = 'localhost'
    #port = 2015
    Csocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    message =' ping' # Client's message to the server
    #data = input("Enter a message in lowercase")

    LastPing = 12 #12 ping messages to be sent
    count = 0
    Csocket.settimeout(1) #timeout after one second
    #print ("Attempting to send " , count , "messages" )

    while count  < LastPing: #while attempting to send to 12 times
        count = count + 1 #incrementing the counter
        startTime = time.time() # Start time when the message from the client is being sent
        print(message , startTime , count) # Printing the clien't message as per required format
        Csocket.sendto(message, (serverName, port)) #sends the message in the socket

        try:
            newmsg, address = Csocket.recvfrom(1024) # Reply message from server in uppercase form
            RTT = ((time.time()) - startTime) #Calculating the Round Trip Time for each packet
            mylist.append(RTT)
            a = sum(mylist)
            b = len(mylist)
            average=a/b
            print "Uppercase Message from the Server: ", newmsg
            print "The Round Trip Time is: " + str(RTT) + " seconds"

        except timeout:
            print" Client's Request timed out\n"
        except Exception as e:
            print e
    print "The program is done"
    print "Stored RTTs are: ", mylist
    print "Total number of successful packets is: ",b
    print "Max RTT is: ",str(max(mylist)) + " seconds"
    print "Min RTT is: ",str(min(mylist)) + " seconds"
    print "Sum of all RTTs is: ",str(a) + " seconds"
    print "Average Round Trip Time is: ",average
#def median(mylist):
    sortedLst = sorted(mylist)
    lstLen = len(mylist)
    index = (lstLen - 1) // 2

    if (lstLen % 2):
        return sortedLst[index]
    else:
        return (sortedLst[index] + sortedLst[index + 1])/2.0
    print "Median RTT is: " (mylist) + "seconds"
    Csocket.close
#median(mylist)

main()
```

Comment: Can you show the invalid values and possibly a stacktrace?

Comment: my mistake. RTT values are being stored correctly. I have modified the code and now the median RTT is not showing. Giving me an error: IndexError: list index out of range. Could you please help?

Comment: Please post everything you know, so that we can try debugging from the same knowledge.

Comment: Never mind, I was able to figure out the issue. I was trying to calculate the median of the RTT stored in mylist but somehow the list was empty(which was declared in the beginning). Hence the index was out of range since there was no item in the initial mylist[].

Comment: Thanks for sharing :)